# Why is Random Search showing better results than Grid Search?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm playing with RandomizedSearchCV function from scikit-learn. Some academic paper claims that Randomized Search can provide 'good enough' results comparing with a whole grid search, but saves a lot of time.

Surprisingly, on one occasion, the RandomizedSearchCV provided me better results than GridSearchCV. I think GridSearchCV is suppose to be exhaustive, so the result has to be better than RandomizedSearchCV suppose they search through the same grid.

for the same dataset and mostly same settings, GridsearchCV returned me the following result:
Best cv accuracy: 0.7642857142857142
Test set score:   0.725
Best parameters:  'C': 0.02

the RandomizedSearchCV returned me the following result:
Best cv accuracy: 0.7428571428571429
Test set score:   0.7333333333333333
Best parameters:  'C': 0.008

To me the test score of 0.733 is better than 0.725, and the difference between test score and training score for the RandomizedSearchCV is smaller, which to my knowledge means less overfitting.

So why did GridSearchCV return me worse results?

GridSearchCV code:

```
def linear_SVC(x, y, param, kfold):
    param_grid = {'C':param}
    k = KFold(n_splits=kfold, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=k, n_jobs=4, verbose=1)

    return grid.fit(x, y)

#high C means more chance of overfitting

start = timer()
param = [i/1000 for i in range(1,1000)]
param1 = [i for i in range(1,101)]
param.extend(param1)

#progress = progressbar.bar.ProgressBar()
clf = linear_SVC(x=x_train, y=y_train, param=param, kfold=3)

print('LinearSVC:')
print('Best cv accuracy: {}' .format(clf.best_score_))
print('Test set score:   {}' .format(clf.score(x_test, y_test)))
print('Best parameters:  {}' .format(clf.best_params_))
print()

duration = timer() - start
print('time to run: {}' .format(duration))
```

RandomizedSearchCV code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

def Linear_SVC_Rand(x, y, param, kfold, n):
    param_grid = {'C':param}
    k = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=kfold, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    randsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_distributions=param_grid, cv=k, n_jobs=4,
                                    verbose=1, n_iter=n)

    return randsearch.fit(x, y)

start = timer()
param = [i/1000 for i in range(1,1000)]
param1 = [i for i in range(1,101)]
param.extend(param1)

#progress = progressbar.bar.ProgressBar()
clf = Linear_SVC_Rand(x=x_train, y=y_train, param=param, kfold=3, n=100)

print('LinearSVC:')
print('Best cv accuracy: {}' .format(clf.best_score_))
print('Test set score:   {}' .format(clf.score(x_test, y_test)))
print('Best parameters:  {}' .format(clf.best_params_))
print()

duration = timer() - start
print('time to run: {}' .format(duration))
```

Comment: You know that you are using KFold in GridSearchCV and StratifiedKFold in RandomizedSearchCV? And do you know that they will yield different folds each time?

Comment: Also you should create the LinearSVC with the same random_state variable, just to be sure on reproduceability

Comment: I thought the random state was already set. You mean I need to set another one for the LinearSVC itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, try to understand this:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation

*So you should know that StratifiedKFold is better than KFold.*

Use StratifiedKFold in both GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV. Make sure to set "`shuffle = False`" and not use "`random_state`" parameter. What this does: the dataset you are using will not be shuffled so that your results won't be changed each time you train it. You might get what you expect.

GridSearchCV code:

```
def linear_SVC(x, y, param, kfold):
    param_grid = {'C':param}
    k = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=kfold)
    grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=k, n_jobs=4, verbose=1)

    return grid.fit(x, y)
```

RandomizedSearchCV code:

```
def Linear_SVC_Rand(x, y, param, kfold, n):
    param_grid = {'C':param}
    k = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=kfold)
    randsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_distributions=param_grid, cv=k, n_jobs=4,
                                    verbose=1, n_iter=n)

    return randsearch.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I now understand why am I getting inconsistent results.

Comment: you can directly use `cv=kfold` as stated in the doc: cv: - integer, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold,

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like it is performing properly. Your train/cv set accuracy in gridsearch is higher than train/cv set accuracy in randomized search. The hyper parameters should not be tuned using the test set, so assuming you're doing that properly it might just be a coincidence that the hyper parameters that were chosen from randomized search performed better on the test set.